# html css div width not relative to child tables

Tags: html, css

I'd like an table to have relative width each others in div. How to do if one table has a big picture or long word, so the other tables in same div also extends to 100% as first one.
Please see in example:

CSS

```
.outer {
    border: solid 3px green;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
table {
    border: solid 1px red;
    width: 100%;
}
.label {
    border: solid 3px red;
    width: 20%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
      <table >
        <tr>
          <td class="label">
                 Label 01
          </td>          
          <td>
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq  s
          </td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="label">
                 Label 02
          </td>                  
          <td>
    meworks & Extensionsotools More 1.3.1 (compat)
    ART 0.8.7 PowerTools 1.0.5 Fiddle Options External Resources
    Languages Results Ajax RequestsLegal, Credits and Links
          </td>  
        </tr>      
      </table>
    </div>
```

Here is my **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mindaugelis/2bHcu/1/)**

Comment: your fiddle scared me....can u rephrase what u want???

Comment: Don't use tables for layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For answering just the question,

```
    display: table;
```

for the 'outer' div will do.

Answer (score 0):

```
table td {word-wrap: break-word;}
```

But must be words, not just "aaaaaaaaaaaadddddddddd".